# Where to register custom RegionManager WPF Prism5

Tags: mvvm, wpf-4.0, prism-4

I have added an additional method called `CustomRequestNavigate(string, Uri);` in region manger. Right now question is where to register this to container and replace IRegionManger implementation that comes out of the box in Prism

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to how to do this.

Once you have replacement type for any prism default types you will have to override ConfigureContainer() and register your types as follows

```
    // when using Unity
protected override void ConfigureContainer()
{
    this.RegisterTypeIfMissing(typeof(IEventAggregator), typeof(ReplacementEventAggregator), true);

    base.ConfigureContainer();
}
```

I followed the same for RegionManager.

Solution is well described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg430866(v=pandp.40).aspx)

Comment: I did the above but it turns out I am running into stackoverflow exception when I try to resolve<IRegionManager>(); not sure why